# How should be structured a correct hidden layer of NN that has 1 input (matrix N*N) and 2 outputs?

Tags: algorithm, math, neural-network, hidden, layer

like we have a grate array of matrices N*N and x1 x2 outputs for them. we want to get a trainable network that would give x1 and x2 close to our data. how should its hidden layer structure look like? I would like if it would not to turn x1 into x2 and x2 into x1.
So I want to build a trainable network that takes an NxN matrix as input and produces two numbers, x1, and x2, as output.

Comment: No offense, but this is almost unintelligible. You want to build a trainable network that takes an NxN matrix as input and produces two numbers, x1, and x2, as output. Is that correct?

Comment: yes it is correct Beta=)

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your hidden layers is not as important as the number of neurons they contain.

Generally, you can use a fully connected network with 1 or 2 hidden layers. 1 hidden layer will work for most problems, but 2 hidden layers ensure that your NN can approximate any possible function. There is no theoretical reason to use more than 2 hidden layers.

The number of neurons in the hidden layers will determine how precise the NN will be. The more neurons you have, the better you will approximate the function. BUT more neurons imply more variables in your NN, so you will need a bigger training set. You will also be more likely to over-fit your training data: to avoid that, use separate training and testing sets to monitor when the over-fitting occurs.

So the answer really depends on how big your dataset is. The bigger, the better, the more neurons you can have, the more accurate your NN will be. To find experimentally how many neurons you should use, you can try different numbers and use [cross validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29) to evaluate the NN obtained.

Comment: Main question is how do I need to create neurons to eat that N*N matrix?

Comment: I'm afraid I do not understand your question... can you reformulate?